# How to move a cell in GridLayout - QML?

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout, qtquick2, qt5.4

Considering the [documentation of GridLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html), here is what I have tried:

---

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window
{
    visible: true

    MainForm
    {
        GridLayout {
            id: gridLayout
            columns: 3

            height: 100
            width: 100
            property int oneRow: 0
            property int oneCol: 0

            Rectangle { id: one; Layout.row :gridLayout.oneRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.oneCol;
                height: 50; width: 50; color: "brown"}

            Rectangle { height: 50; width: 50; color: "red" }
            Rectangle { height: 50; width: 50; color: "blue"}
            Rectangle { height: 50; width: 50; color: "green"}
            Rectangle { height: 50; width: 50; color: "yellow"}
        }

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            gridLayout.oneRow = 2
            gridLayout.oneCol = 2
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out this code from `Component.onCompleted`,

```
gridLayout.oneRow = 2
gridLayout.oneCol = 2
```

I get:

[image]

***Whereas I want that brown square to "move to" the second row's last column.***
So, I wrote:

```
gridLayout.oneRow = 1
gridLayout.oneCol = 2
```

in `Component.onCompleted`.

but then, I got the following:

[image]

***which is NOT what I wanted.***

Please help.

Comment: What if you set the Brown rectangle last in your declaration?

Comment: @Thomas there is a reason I double quoted the words "move to" in OP.

Comment: I see a *lot* of weird things here, sorry if the stupidness of my question hurt you

Comment: Does the [Layout.row (&column)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#row-attached-prop) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to change the cell number of some item in the `GridLayout`, then  you need to assign the initial [row number and column number](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#row-attached-prop)  to all the elements ***_yourself_***, and then change the position of the desired item dynamically as shown below:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window
{
    visible: true

    MainForm
    {
        GridLayout {
            id: gridLayout

            height: 100
            width: 100

            property int oneRow: 0
            property int oneCol: 0
            Rectangle { id: one;
                Layout.row :gridLayout.oneRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.oneCol;
                height: 50; width: 50; color: "brown"}

            property int twoRow: 0
            property int twoCol: 1
            Rectangle { id: two;
                Layout.row :gridLayout.twoRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.twoCol;
                height: 50; width: 50; color: "red" }

            property int threeRow: 0
            property int threeCol: 2
            Rectangle { id: three;
                Layout.row :gridLayout.threeRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.threeCol;
                height: 50; width: 50; color: "blue"}

            property int fourRow: 1
            property int fourCol: 0
            Rectangle { id: four;
                Layout.row :gridLayout.fourRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.fourCol;
                height: 50; width: 50; color: "green"}

            property int fiveRow: 1
            property int fiveCol: 1
            Rectangle { id: five;
                Layout.row :gridLayout.fiveRow; Layout.column: gridLayout.fiveCol;
                height: 50; width: 50; color: "yellow"}
        }

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            gridLayout.oneRow = 1
            gridLayout.oneCol = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see the following code in `Component.onCompleted` moves the brown rectangle to the 2nd row's 3rd column.

```
Component.onCompleted:
  {
      gridLayout.oneRow = 1
      gridLayout.oneCol = 2
  }
```

[image]